# How does ASCII 0x00A0 becomes 0x00E1

Tags: c#, excel, parsing, encoding, ascii

I'm reverse engineering a old parser application and the ASCII code 00A0 ("NO-BREAK SPACE") from a text file, is being parsed into 00E1 ("LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH ACUTE").

What kind of encoding or coercion is happening, and how can I reproduce this behavior in C# ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like the CP 850 (DOS) encoding: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850

You can get an encoding for that code page via `Encoding.GetEncoding(850)`.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding?view=net-5.0

Bear in mind that there are multiple, similar code pages that vary slightly. Because... standards.

Comment: I still don't quite get how the value fits on the table but will research more about it. For now reading the text file in C# with GetEncoding(850) solved the problem

Comment: @VictorPanisa — Because your "string" is nothing more than a sequence of octets (bytes). And an _encoding_ (and a WIndows "code page" **is** an encoding) is nothing more than **a** mapping of 1 or more octets to visual glyphs. There are many such mappings — ASCII, EBCDIC(which itself comes in multiple flavors), many different WIndows code pages, [ISO-8859](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859#Table) which has some 16 different ways to map 0xA0-0xFF. And Unicode, which isn't and encoding but has UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32 (and others).